# JavaScript error on Stack Overflow "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: bug, status-completed

On Stack Overflow (rev 2015.9.9.2796) the Google Analytics snippet has one `}` too many:

```
ga('create', 'UA-5620270-1'});
                           ^
```

Or when logged in:

```
ga('create', 'UA-5620270-1', {'userId': '10202' }});
                                                 ^
```

Comment: Seeing the same on latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Whoops.

That extra `}` has been removed - the fix will be out there in the next build.

Comment: On the risk of getting suspended for harassing SE employees: shouldn't jslint/jshint have caught that on build? ...  ;)  */me hides for a couple of hours...*

Comment: @rene - it normally would, but this bit of code lives in a razor view and not its own JS file. If it were a regular JS file, our build would have failed indeed.